# Triplets, Sampling Criteria and Variance?

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, standard-error, probabilistic-forecasts

Say I have a population size of 1000 students from schools in different towns (assume they are in the same class year, of mixed gender, same country/state). The mean, variance and standard deviation of their height is M0, V0 and ST0.

From this, I create three subsets

- Subset 1 (a random sampling of 100 students = M1, V1 and ST1),
- Subset 2 (all 100 students in the same school =M2, V2 and ST2), and
- Subset 3 (30 students who are related genetically e.g. twins/triplets, cousins, half-siblings = M3, V3 and ST3).

My two questions are

1. How does the magnitude of mean, variation and deviation on the subset level compare to the total population size e.g. is M1/V1/ST1 >  M0/V0/ST0 but M1/V1/ST1 < M3/V3/ST3?
2. I want to predict the average height of an incoming new set of triplets into the school system i.e. growing the total population size from 1000 to 1003. Which P50 would give me the closest answer - that for the total population size, or that of the different subsets?

Thanks!!

Comment: M1/V1 ~ M0/V0 since M1/V1 since a SRS gives an unbiased estimates for the population mean and variance.